# extract the value between two parameters oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract the string *01-DEC-17* from '123|01-DEC-17|-123'. But I am not getting desired output:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('123|01-DEC-17|-123', INSTR('123|01-DEC-17|-123','|', 1)+1, INSTR('123|01-DEC-17|-123', '|',-1)+1)
FROM DUAL;
```

Output is coming as `01-DEC-17|-123`. but the desired output is `01-DEC-17`. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexp_substr()`.  Here is one method:

```
select trim(both '|' from regexp_substr(col, '|[^|]+|'))
```

Or, if you know that the positions are fixed, you can just use `substr()`:

```
select substr(col, 5, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with t (col)
as (
    select '123|01-DEC-17|-123'
    from dual
    )
select substr(
    col, 
    instr(col, '|') + 1, 
    instr(col, '|', 1, 2) - instr(col, '|') - 1
    )
from t;
```

`instr(col, '|')` - Location of first occurrence of `|`
`instr(col, '|', 1, 2)` - Location of second occurrence of `|`

For `substr(column, start_position, length)`, We need length of subtring as third parameter to substr, so,

`instr(col, '|', 1, 2) - instr(col, '|') - 1` will give us the required length.

Comment: I used your logic and this works
SELECT SUBSTR('123|01-DEC-17|-123', INSTR('123|01-DEC-17|-123','|', 1)+1, INSTR('123|01-DEC-17|-123', '|',-1)-1-INSTR('123|01-DEC-17|-123','|', 1))
FROM DUAL;

Comment: @user2632670 - Glad to help. Please consider accepting the answers if they are useful. I can see you have accepted none of the answers from your previous questions.